# How is a sleep mode of a micro-controller realized?

Tags: microcontroller, power, pcb, energy

- How can a micro-controller save energy?
- What does it mean if the micro-controller throttles its CPU?
- How can a micro-controller "turn off peripherals" that are not needed to save energy?

I guess everything has to do with the clock frequency and power signal.

- If there is no clock signal on a component, it will be turned off?
- However, how do I realize that there is no clock signal at a component (transistor?) or that for some components the clock frequency is slower?

Comment: It's a very vague question. Pick microcontroller of your choice, gets its documentation, you should have plenty of info how to operate it in low power or various sleep modes and how they function. Vote to close because "needs more focus" (you CAN ask about some specific microcontroller if you also do some research about it yourself and don't understand something)

Comment: I don't find something with more depth. Typically, they say that sleep-modes are realized by turning off the CPU or other unused components on the chip. How that is done is not described. :/ And how does a timer still work when my clock signal is turned off? Is the oscillator still running, and my components are just disconnected?

Comment: It's often done via software. Depends very much on specific MCU. It's all described in great detail in datasheets, but you obviously need to know some basic stuff about how MCU works, how it supplies clock to different parts and can just power/unpower pieces of itself on software or sometimes even hardware trigger. Give some STM32 Datasheet and Reference Manual a look, see how they implement it. Just as an example. They describe stuff fairly well (but it's a lot of info, confusing at first)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I just look into some datashet and seems that you have multiple clocks. E.g. you have HCLK which you can further "divide" and also you have PLCKX "Peripheral clock" that you can turn on and off. However, I am still missing if they have all the same oscillator.

Comment: in case of STM32 you can configure that (what uses what oscillator) as well. STM32 have 2 internal clocks (e.g. 16MHz and precisely 32kHz), but it can also operate two external clocks (e.g. 25MHz and 32768Hz RTC clock) and you can choose what clock to use for what. Within limits. It's all in the spec. Arduino MCU (Atmega328) isn't nearly as complex, for instance.

Comment: Thanks again! :) I guess I could look into the datasheet, however you are probably an expert on the STM32. If I go to power-save, I can just switch the CPU from 16 MHz clock to 32 kHz clock?

Comment: Not even remotely an expert, I'm learning it. And yes, you can switch clocks on the fly and choose what parts of the system to disable, even unpower RAM and use backup registers (which I have no idea how to do myself, something I will learn some day, there is a huge amount of stuff to cover for me until then; besides, it's a matter of necessity, which I don't have atm). In case of STM32, yes, you can switch clocks, change clock dividers, unpower all peripherals. Again, very device-specific. Some STM32 are tailored for low power and can go below microamp.

Answer (score 3):

> How can a micro-controller save energy?

Energy is consumed through two processes, leakage (where current flows through off transistors) and switching (where a transistor does something using energy).  Saving power therefore reduces to setting clock speeds only as fast as they need to and turning off voltage to things when they're not needed.

For example, years ago I worked on an ARM microcontroller system for an MP3 player.  Our optimized decoder could play MP3s or Vorbis files at ~25 MHz.  To save power, the system would regularly check how much decoded audio was available, and if it was more than 1/4 of a second, it would lower the CPU clock.  If it was less, it would raise it.  Therefore we avoided wasting CPU cycles doing nothing, producing on average just 25M cycles per second, plus whatever was needed to handle the user pushing buttons.

In addition, the device had a storage controller that used energy whenever it was on.  To save power, we would read ahead of the current position in the MP3 into RAM, trying to buffer 3-4 MB at a time (about 2-3 minutes).  In between reads, we would power down the storage entirely (turn off its clock and power down the voltage converter used for the storage) so that it wouldn't waste energy doing nothing.

Together these changes and lots of other similar ones increased how long the device could run on a charge from 7-8 hours to 25-30 hours.

> How can a micro-controller "turn off peripherals" that are not needed to save energy?

> However, how do I realize that there is no clock signal at a component (transistor?) or that for some components the clock frequency is slower?

Internally the microcontroller may need to do lots of complicated things to prepare a device to power down (save state, cut clocks, flush buffers, etc) and then reverse them to power back up.  From a software perspective, usually there is a register in memory that acts as an "on/off" switch.  Write a one and the hardware will turn it on.  Zero and off.  The hardware designer will then make that bit control whatever processes need to happen to physically disconnect the clock and/or voltage.

In the MP3 player above, there was a single 32 bit register in memory at an address above the RAM.  Each bit of the register was one peripheral device.

> However, how do I realize that there is no clock signal at a component (transistor?) or that for some components the clock frequency is slower?

Typically the same registers that turn devices off or lower clocks are also readable, so if you were confused you could read them back.  However, software will need to manage its own state, so typically you always know what is on and what is off.  If you didn't, you will have problems, like trying to read unpowered storage. At boot up, we put each peripheral into a known state (since the bootloader was not documented and did some strange things) and then internal variables in the operating system kept track of each new change to the hardware state so that the software always knew what was on and what was off.

Answer (score 1):

In very general terms, the power consumed by CMOS logic (including MCUs) has two components, leakage current and switching current. Leakage current is the tiny current that flows through a transistor even when it is supposed to be "off". All of the gates on a chip consume a constant amount of current as a result.

When CMOS logic is switched from one state to the other, a certain amount of charge needs to be moved into or out of a circuit node that includes the gates of transistors and the wiring among them. The total of all these current pulses is known as switching current. Switching current tends to scale linearly with clock speed, dropping to zero if the clock isn't cycling at all.

In a chip designed specifically for low-power operation, pains are taken to make leakage current as small as possible, so the marjority of the power consumed is due to switching current.

So, to save power when operating from batteries, some MCUs have "low power modes", which usually involve stopping the clock to certain subsystems, sometimes including the CPU itself. This is accomplished using internal gates, not by any sort of external logic. This eliminates the switching current for those subsystems.

If the clock oscillator is built into the MCU (i.e., there is just a crystal connected to the MCU pins), then the oscillator will actually stop operating during the lowest-power modes. If an external oscillator is used, then it is up to the PCB designer to decide how to manage its power.

To save additional power, it may be possible to also eliminate the leakage current for some subsystems, which involves using an internal transistor in series with the power supply to those subsystems.

Answer (score 0):

Information can be found at datasheet. Different microcontrollers may have the different way to go to standby mode. Usually the main clock stops. Some MCU have a few clock. Wake up from standby mode can be performed by using external signal or internal signal from for instance watchdog timer, which runs on separate clock. That clock runs with lower frequency, so the consumption is very low. Whole processes stops, programm counter and work registers saved, outputs not changing, except may be some MCU have tri-state outputs.

Comment: "Usually the main clock stops." How is that realized? Do I remove the power from my oscillator?

Comment: @user674907 everything we talk about here is microcontroller-specific. But it's all usually done in software in modern MCUs. But not necessarily, I haven't read all datasheets.

Comment: Simplest way is an AND gate - clock signal to a peripheral can be either kept on or turned off.